# PATM Generator GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, gui, user-interface

I've been practising trying to write my code neater, so decided to build a practice GUI, the code works, However, how could I tidy this up in terms of separating out the different parts of the GUI, such as a separate defs for labels, Combobox etc? or using a function for the 'with open' section.

```py
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title('PATM Generator')
        master.geometry('+600+300')

        #Label1
        master.label1 = Label(root, text = 'Select test bed:')
        master.label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5)

        #Combobox
        master.combo = Combobox(root)
        master.combo.grid(row =1, column = 0)
        master.combo['values'] = (TB)

        #Label2
        master.label2 = Label(root, text = 'Enter TRD index:')
        master.label2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5)

        #Entry
        master.entry = Entry(root)
        master.entry.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 0)

        #Button
        master.button = Button(root, text = 'Append to txt')
        master.button.grid(row = 4, padx = 10, pady = 5)

with open('TB.txt') as inFile:
    TB = [line for line in inFile]

def main():
    GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: the comments do not add additional information, I would just remove them.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What task does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question via [edit]. Maybe you missed the placeholder on the title element: "_State the task that your code accomplishes. Make your title distinctive._". Also from  [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". e.g. _PATM generator_?

Comment: [I edited the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/260066/3) so it describes the code. Feel free to [edit] it if you feel there is a more appropriate title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give an example of your text file, maybe that would shed some light on the use of a combo box instead of a text widget.
You started out with using self in your class but soon used master.

> master.combo = Combobox(root)

Using self. prefix allows you to access the objects, widgets and any other data in other functions.

```
apple
orange
banana
grape
grapefruit
tangerine
```

combo_stuff.txt

So I'm guessing that you want to add whatever is typed into the entry widget to your text file- Here's one way to accomplish it.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.ttk import *



class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('PATM Generator')
        self.master.geometry('+600+300')

        #Label1
        self.label1 = Label(root, text = 'Select test bed')  
        self.label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5)

        #Combobox
        self.combo = Combobox(root)
        self.combo.grid(row =1, column = 0)
        self.combo['values'] = (TB)

        #Label2
        self.label2 = Label(root, text = 'Enter TRD index:')
        self.label2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5)

        #Entry
        self.entry = Entry(root)
        self.entry.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 0)

        #Button
        self.button = Button(root, text = 'Append to txt',
                           command=self.append_text)
        self.button.grid(row = 4, padx = 10, pady = 5)
    def append_text(self):
        item= self.entry.get()
        if item: # insure there's text in the entry
            print(item)
        
            with open('combo_stuff.txt', mode='a',) as write_file:
                write_file.write('\n' + item)
                write_file.close()
            self.entry.delete(0,'end')
        

with open('combo_stuff.txt') as inFile:
    TB = [line for line in inFile]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The easiest way to open a file is with the pre-made dialog.
here's a link to some examples :
[tkinter file dialog](https://pythonbasics.org/tkinter-filedialog/)

Answer (score 2):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

instead of

```
def main():
    GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

it's the "pythonic" way of accomplishing what you've written.

Comment: Using `main()` _and_ `if __name__ == "__main__":` is common as then you can make `main` a setuptool's console entrypoint and have the `if` handle `python -m name` invocation.